# Tfs 2017 Publish buid artifacts

Tags: build, artifact

I've been working on a project under TFS 2017 and i want to publish build artifacts in the source directory. Any help? Thank you!

Comment: Why you want to publish the build artifacts to the source directory? And what's the problem when you publish build artifacts to the source directory?

Answer (score 0):

Generally it will copy files from `$(build.sourcesdirectory)` to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`, then publish artifacts to **Server** or **File Share**.

So ,not sure why you want to publish the build artifacts **back to** the source directory.

Whatever, you can simply select **File Share** as the `Artifact Type` and change the path to `$(build.sourcesdirectory)` in `Publish Build Artifacts` task.

[image]